# How to match and mark only two words, but with a string between them?

Tags: regex

I would like to match "sentence" and "beautiful", only these two words and only if they are in a close range of each other, but without the words between them.

The example is:

```
This is a sentence, it is beautiful.
```

I would would like to match "sentence" and "beatiful", if they are close to each other and only them. Everything I tried, I always match everything between them or I have to make two capturing Groups.

Tried:

```
\b(?i)(?:sentence.{0,50}beautiful)\b
\b(?i)(?:(sentence).{0,50}(beautiful))\b
\b(?i)(?:sentence(?=.{0,50}beautiful))\b
```

Result:

```
Full Match: sentence, it is beautiful
Full Match: sentence, it is beautiful, Group 1: sentence, Group 2: beautiful
Full Match: sentence
```

I also tried other variations, but I am not able to just show me my keywords "sentence beautiful", without anything between them. Is it possible just with Regex to just show me the keywords?
Thanks for any input!

Comment: This is rather a strange requirement. See `/\bsentence\b(?=.{0,50}\bbeautiful\b)|(?<=\bsentence\b.{0,50})\bbeautiful\b/i` at https://regex101.com/r/cNjLae/1/, but it would probably be something much simpler if you explained 1) what exactly you are doing and 2) what programming language you are using.

Comment: Try
(^.*?sentence)(\W+\w+){0,3}(\sbeautiful.*$)
where the maximum number of intervening "words" can be increased from 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to search for this:

```
.*?(sentence).{0,50}?(beautiful).*
```

and then replace it with:

```
\1 \2
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/yTMhgG/1).